# Ember.JS Computed Properties

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I am trying to create some computed properties with an Ember ObjectController and am experiencing some difficulties. My object (Baz) contains an array of objects (Foo). Each Foo has some key/value pairs, let's call them alpha and beta.

Using code like this:

```
App.BazController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    total: function() {
        return this.get('foos').getEach('alpha').reduce(function(accum, item) {
            return accum + item;
        }, 0);
    }.property('foos.@each.alpha')
});
```

I can calculate the sum of every Foo object's 'alpha' property but I would like to calculate values between specific Foos, ideally selected by their built-in ID. I have tried a fairly wide variety of expressions to try and select an individual Foo object out of the array but I can't seem to figure it out.

Can this be accomplished within an ObjectController or is this the wrong place to try and compute such values?

Any help from code to a conceptual walkthrough would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers,
Allen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access properties of the `item` in the `reduce` method while building up the `total`. For instance to find total of products but only if they are `inStock` and `onSale`, you can use.

```
totalByReduce: function() {
  return this.get('model').reduce(function(total, product) {
    if (product.get('inStock') && product.get('onSale')) {
      return total + product.get('price');
    } else {
      return total;
    }
  }, 0);
}.property('model.@each')
```

Likewise if you are doing the filtering in multiple stages, ie:- filtering then reducing, you can have 2 different computed properties that depend on each other. For instance, if you only display products that are `inStock` and `onSale`,

```
saleProducts: function() {
  return this.get('model').filter(function(product) {
    return product.get('inStock') && product.get('onSale');
  });
}.property('model.@each'),
```

Then to get the `total` of `saleProducts` you can setup a 2nd computed property like,

```
total: function() {
  return this.get('saleProducts').reduce(function(total, product) {
    return total + product.get('price');
  }, 0);
}.property('saleProducts.@each'),
```

Here's a [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/asehes/2/edit) example.